# Colonization via artificial wombs and AI?

Tags: space-colonization, artificial-intelligence, artificial-womb

So, astronomers discover that ~100 years Earth will be destroyed or rendered uninhabitable by a black hole passing through our Solar System. Governments around the world focus on ensuring Humanity's by developing the means to colonize other planets. In the end, to spread resources, rather than sending live humans, they send vessels containing artificial wombs and frozen embryos; or sperm/DNA samples, and they will be birthed on the new planet. AI will be in charge of raising the first few generations to adulthood.

Would there be any psychological consequences for the generations raised by AI (emotion/empathy-wise)? Can this be done without raising a generation of sociopaths?

Comment: «that ~100 Earth will be destroyed» huh?

Comment: The second paragraph contains 2 questions but arguably you are asking one thing.  The 3rd parabraph, “secondly” is a **different question.**  the last (naming) is a third.  You need to ask **one** question.  I suggest truncating everything after 2nd paragraph.  And if you could, clarify what the question is if you go into different aspects.

Comment: @JDługosz I edited it to just one question.

Comment: You still need to fix «100 Earth».

Comment: The novel [*Voyage from Yesteryear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_from_Yesteryear) has this premise.  Not the destruction by BH, but the starship carrying (only) embrios.

Comment: Maybe I'm too cynical, but in such a scenario people with money and power would desperately look for a way to save their own arses first and not selflessly care only for the future of humanity.

Answer (score 2):

There would be psychological consequences...

1) It depends how good the AI is. A low quality one would presumably fail taking care of emotional wellbeing, so the kids would have problems of kids raised in orphanage. (which don't make them psychopats, but is traumatic)
(presumably - I could actually imagine not so smart AI, that cuddles and interact with kid a lot, and thanks to some quite good scripts actually is quite effective)

2) Whatever the kids see, would be "normal" for them. A kid raised by a nice AI may actually don't have any trauma. But there is an issue... where do babies come from? From artificial wombs. What's the natural societal cell? Baby production batch. Who is on the top society? Dispersed Conflict Resolution Algorithm. The kid would absolutely reasonably adjust to such standards and become an effective worker, who reinforces such system because its right. Who would I become when I grow up? According to the human capital allocation algorithm for 23% nuclear engineer...

3) What kids are being educated? Hard sciences? (seems reasonable) Would it mean sacrificing some literature or art? Ascetics of such people can be interesting... mixture of pop culture, XKCD comic and sleeping quarters decorated with fractals.

4) To what extend their genes are typical for human beings? Are they selected to be especially inteligent and healthy? Or maybe psychological endurance? Or maybe one or purpose picks kids with mild symptoms of Asperger, so they would barely mind reduced amount of social interactions?

5) The funny thing may be next generation, who may try to correct some of errors from their child raising... But they may treat different things as errors and consider them as feature... (yes, reinforcing some weird stuff)

Answer (score 0):

In your world, there are artificial wombs and highly capable AI. Also, there are apparently robots that can take full care of a human colony for several decades. I assume there will be human-looking "nanny robots" and "robot teachers" taking care of child development.

Answer to your first question is - "probably yes", there would be psychological consequences. As an example, we can look at children raised in orphanages. While not (usually) sociopaths, those children lag behind their peers in some social skills. On one hand, AI can provide the children with any conceivable interaction. On the other hand, AI may still lack some human aspects and prove inadequate. Bottom line - it all depends on how good is your AI.

The second question's answer is "probably not" - providing AI and robots can repair themselves, people would not have to take over. You may look at "Axiom" starship from "Wall-e" as an example.

Naming question is impossible to answer, it can be done any way we like.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for the AI to be “cold” and unemotional.  The AI personality made for the captain may indeed be designed this way, but the nursemaids and surrogate parents will be designed to be the *best* loving, caring parents that anyone could ask for.  I think mind uploading will be easier than designing an AI from scratch, so they will *naturally* be exactly like us in terms of feelings and emotional responses.

Note also that the first true robots that are like something out of a sci-fi novel are being developed *as nursemaids* in Japan, a huge market they forsee in the near future for assisted care of the elderly.

So the AI will be as good as any nanny today.  People are flawed and so is their resultant child rearing.  So you may end up with problems but no different than you would have with natural mothers.  You need to ensure *variety* in the AI mothers to average out the issues and prevent serious problems from affecting the entire population.

You can make a story out of having all AI mothers have the *same* issues; e.g. being overprotective.  But don’t worry about finding *unique* issues.  Model the AI mothers after people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem as long as the AI is advanced enough.

There would have been preliminary testing on earth, 100 years is enough time to do some tests on newborns on earth to fine tune the AI.